# R: creating a new variable based on a boolean variable

Tags: r

I have a boolean variable (e.g. x <- c(T, T, F, T, F,...)) and I want to create a second variable based on my boolean variable. If x == T, then my new variable should take value "A", otherwise, it should take a value of "B". I know it seems easy, but I am new to this.

Comment: This is a traditional `if...else...` question. Please see a guide on `r` and search for `if...else...` and you will find many examples and explanations on how to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a variable `y`based on the boolean vector `x`use:

`y <- ifelse(x == T, "A", "B")`

The first argument of `ifelse` is the test, i.e. *if* x == TRUE, the second argument is what should be done if x == TRUE, the third argument is what should be done if x == FALSE.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
q <- ifelse(x, "A", "B")
```